# I am getting the wrong result for north coordinate

Tags: python, pyproj

```
from pyproj import Proj

#converting lat/long - UTM
lats = -22.818009494
longs = -47.059235202
alt = 644.2332


myProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=23K, +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
x, y = myProj(longs, lats)

print (x, y)
```

I'm running this code and I'm getting this result below:

[image]

The E coordinate is right; however, the N coordinate is wrong

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? Because of the negative value?

Comment: It is wrong because I know the correct answer LOL....

Comment: Could you add the correct one?

Comment: 288652.545 7475152.818.  which is interesting that it worked in my previous UBUNTU. I don't know after uploading it's not working.

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370838/pyproj-giving-negative-utm-northing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use the [`transform`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#pyproj.transformer.Transformer.transform) method  in [`Transformer`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#transformer) class.

```
from pyproj import Transformer

# 4326: WGS84 (source), 32723: UTM Zone23S (target)
transformer = Transformer.from_crs(4326, 32723)

lat = -22.818009494
long = -47.059235202

x, y = transformer.transform(lat, long)

print (x, y)

# 288652.54449622496 7475152.999493342
```

Answer (score 11):

It might be related to the proj string you specified. Use `CRS` instead of the proj string.

```
from pyproj import Proj, CRS 

#converting lat/long - UTM
lat = -22.818009494
long = -47.059235202

crs = CRS.from_epsg(32723)  # 32723 -> UTM Zone 23S

myProj = Proj(crs)
x, y = myProj(long, lat)

print (x, y)

# OUT: 288652.54449622496 7475152.999493342
```

[What is the best format for describing coordinate reference systems?](https://proj.org/faq.html#what-is-the-best-format-for-describing-coordinate-reference-systems)

Answer (score 8):

The issue is the stray comma and unnecessary latitude band K. With the proj string, [`+zone=`](https://proj.org/operations/projections/utm.html#cmdoption-arg-zone) must be a value between 1-60, so just use 23 without a comma:

```
myProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=23 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
x, y = myProj(longs, lats)
print(x, y)
# 288652.54449622496 7475152.999493342
```

If you are able to use pyproj version 2 or later, take advantage of the CRS/Transformer classes, as detailed in the other answers.

Comment: Interesting! Are commas ever used in valid proj strings?

Comment: Commas are not expected for +zone (so this is partially a bug), but they are valid for multi-parameter terms e.g. +towgs84=-199.87,74.79,246.62